# animate div flash light

Tags: animation, css

how to animate plus one div like this site...i just copy and paste css but nothing happend.

http://vbiran.ir

please help me to make somthing like this

my code is somthing like this `googleplus{position:absolute;top:100px;right:310px;background:#F3EBDB;border:1px solid #C3B8A3;padding:14px 6px;-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;animation:googleplus 2s infinite;-moz-animation:googleplus 2s infinite;-webkit-animation:googleplus 2s infinite;font-family:BKoodakBold !important}`

Answer (score 2):

That is made with CSS3 animations. You specify the name of the animation, then describe it with `@keyframes` property. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) for further details, and [here is working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shevchuk/56RAm).